# Google App Engine /del url error

Tags: java, jsp, google-app-engine, servlets

I'm getting an error when I try to delete via link /del. It gives me this error, as shown bellow:

```
Error: Not Found
The requested URL /del?eid=5769015641243648 was not found on this server.
```

I think it has something to do with my servlet mapping or what?

```
<servlet>
<servlet-name>CreateNewEvent</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>com.Norbu.EventsPortal.ServletCreateEvent</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet>
<servlet-name>DeleteEvent</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>com.Norbu.EventsPortal.ServletDeleteEvent</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>CreateNewEvent</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/add</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<sevlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>DeleteEvent</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/del/*</url-pattern>
</sevlet-mapping>
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>EventsPortal.jsp</welcome-file>
 </welcome-file-list>
```

This is the delete link code that I'm using:

```
<a href="/del?eid=<%=eventid%>">
```

This is the warning message in the log file

```
No handlers matched this URL.
```

Is there anyone that could help me solving the issue I'm having?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check spelling.  You have `sevlet-mapping`